# Plotting a graph in MATLAB with $y$-axis data varies over order from $10^0$ to $10^{-1009}$

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a graph in MATLAB with $x$- axis data varies from $1$ to $15$, where as $y$-axis data varies over order from $10^0$ to $10^{-1009}$. Using 'semilog' or 'set axis I am not able to plot graph for $y$-axis data having order lower that $10^{-150}$. I am getting following error

```
Error using set
Bad property value found.
Object Name :  axes
Property Name : 'YLim'
Values must be increasing and non-NaN.
```

Here is my MATLAB code

```
count = 1:15;
subplot(2, 2, 1)

SAcE = [0.2548 0.18759 0.075788  0.0050042 1.4406e-6  3.437e-17  4.6674e-49 1.1689e-144  7.4999e-358 1.5437e-784  3.9277e-1009  5.0621e-1009 3.6067e-1009 5.0621e-1009 3.6067e-1009];

semilogy(count,SAcE, '-b*','LineWidth',1.0, 'MarkerSize',5, 'MarkerEdgeColor','b')

axis([1 15 1 10^(-1009) ])
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: This is fundamentally a floating point math issue: `7.4999e-358` is less than the smallest double precision floating point value greater than zero that can be represented, `eps(realmin)` (about `4.9407-324`). @mikkola solution is a good workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the array you are plotting, you will likely see something like this:

```
SAcE =

  Columns 1 through 13

0.2548    0.1876    0.0758    0.0050    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 14 through 15

     0         0
```

This indicates that MATLAB is not able to represent values as small as you require, see for example [this question and answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/117149-how-to-stop-matlab-from-rounding-extremely-small-values-to-0) for more information. Instead the very small values are rounded to zero.

I suggest that you do a workaround where you 1) represent your values in MATLAB with larger values (possibly scaled versions of your current ones) that are distinguishable from zero and 2) in your plot, write a custom y-label that shows the correct values of the data. Below is an example for synthetic data:

```
count = 1:5;
really_small_numbers_scaled = exp(exp(-(1:5)));

figure;
ah = axes;
semilogy(count, really_small_numbers_scaled)
yt = get(ah, 'YTick'); % the locations of ticks at y-axis corresponding to really_small_numbers_scaled
ytl = get(ah,'YTickLabel'); % the strings that MATLAB actually shows at the y-axis values corresponding to yt

% Set custom YTick and YTickLabel
yt_new = [1.1 1.2 1.25 1.4];
ytl_new = {'1.1e-10000'; '1.2e-9000'; '1.3e-8000'; '1.45e-5000'; '1.6e-1000'};
set(ah, 'YTick', yt_new, 'YTickLabel', ytl_new);
```